# drupal 7 webform change form input attribute

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have form with alt attribute like below

```
<input type="text" alt="abc">
```

I want to remove **alt** tag with **data-alt** , so it should be like below

```
<input type="text" data-alt="abc">
```

I tried below code but it seems not working

```
function act_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach($form["submitted"] as $newForm)
    {
        foreach($newForm as $keyid=>$frmArr)
        {
            if(isset($frmArr[]["#attributes"]["alt"]))
            {
                    $alt = $frmArr["#attributes"]["alt"];
                    unset($newForm[$keyid]["#attributes"]["alt"]);
                    $newForm[$keyid]["#attributes"]["data-alt"] = $alt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help with way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying the `$form` but only the `$values` in your [**foreach()**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) iterations.

- Either modify the `$form` variable itself:

  ```
  $form[...][$keyid]['#attributes]['data-alt'] = $alt;
  ```
- Or pass the `$value` by [**reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (Preceding ampersand `&`).

  ```
  foreach ($form as &$value) {
      # code...
  }
  ```